# Established onomatopoeic word for sound of rolling chairs?

Tags: single-word-requests, sounds, onomatopoeia

I attempted to search for an onomatopoeic word for a chair rolling the floor- such as an office chair across a tiled surface- but to no avail. All that comes is "scraping" and similar for legged chairs.  While words such as *swivel* and *slide* can be used to describe the action, I cannot find a sound effect word.

Addendum: In to resolve the dispute in the comments, and help clarify, [here](https://youtube.com/shorts/0S5gKKWG7No) is a demonstration without words (unlisted). Just pretend a person is in it.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144963/discussion-on-question-by-rewan-demontay-established-onomatopoeic-word-for-sound); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word [clatter](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clatter) would work well for this:

> to make continuous loud noises by hitting hard objects against each other

used [here](https://www.douglasequipment.com/blog/noise-reducing-caster-wheels-for-the-medical-industry/) in reference to casters:

> Poorly chosen casters can clatter across many kinds of floor surfaces, [...]

Comment: This is the answer I would have written. Feel free to incorporate any of these into yours: https://www.google.com/search?q=rolling+chair+%22clatter%22&tbm=bks ... https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/clatter ... https://www.avosound.com/en-us/sound-effects/search/movement/movement-chair-rolling/

Comment: Alrighty... based on the OP’s video, we’re not talking about a clatter. But it’s still a good word given the right chair and the right floor.

Comment: @TinfoilHat That will be the follow-up question: "I have this supposedly onomatopoeic word; can you find the right circumstances (object, surface) under which it actually makes sense?" :)

Comment: @TinfoilHat: I don't know, that sounds clattery enough to me :)

Answer (score 3):

Rumble: OED:

> 1.a. A low continuous murmuring, grumbling, or growling sound.
>
> (a) Such a sound produced by thunder, heavy vehicles, etc.

> **Origin:** Either (i) a borrowing from Dutch. Or (ii) a borrowing from Middle Low German. Or (iii) **an imitative or expressive formation.** Etymons: Dutch rommelen; Middle Low German rummelen.

Answer (score 3):

For [your particular case](https://youtube.com/shorts/0S5gKKWG7No) I suggest '[whir](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/whir)':

> verb: *to move or transport (a thing, person, etc.) with a whirring sound*
> noun: *an act or sound of whirring*

Comment: This is funny and whirr is what I suggested several years ago for helicopters. Anyway, this sound is for machines and the like.

Comment: @Lambie I thought that might come up :) I realize it is usually used for machines and the like, but since it is onomatopoeic in nature, it can apply to anything making a whirring sound.

Comment: A whirring sound in English involves blades turning. Wheels over the some type of base or ground simply do not whir.